# call an existing step inside a custom step with parameter

Tags: cucumber, calabash, gherkin, calabash-android, calabash-ios

I am using [calabash-android](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/canned_steps.md) to test my app.

I created my own step:

```
Then /^There should be (\d+) customers$/ do |nr_of_customers|
 ...
end
```

after that, I create another step, which needs to call the above existing step, I know I can use macro, so I tried this:

```
Given /^I hosted (\d+) customers$/ do |nr_of_customers|
 #How to pass the nr_of_customers to the macro???
 macro 'There should be nr_of_customers'
 ...
end
```

But, how can I pass the parameter `nr_of_customers` to the macro which calls the other step function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call steps from within steps, you'll end up with a mess of spaghetti code if you do. Instead extract helper methods from your step definitions and call these instead.

e.g.

```
Then /^There should be (\d+) customers$/ do |nr_of_customers|
 expect(customer_count).to be nr_of_customers
end

Given /^I hosted (\d+) customers$/ do |nr_of_customers|
  # do some stuff to set up the customers
  expect(customer_count).to be nr_of_customers
  ...

module StepHelpers
  def customer_count
    ....
```

In addition its bad practice to embed then statements in Givens. Givens are about setting up state not testing consequences so really your given should be something like

```
Given /^I hosted (\d+) customers$/ do |nr_of_customers|
   nr_of_customers.times do
     host_customer
   end
```

And `host_customer` should be helper you created when you wrote the scenarios that showed you could host customers.

Comment: I got `Undefined local variable or method 'customer_count'`, how to invoke the helper function in step definition properly?

Comment: add your module to your World (assuming calabash-android has that). In Cucumber ruby you would do `module MyStepHelper ...end World MyStepHelper`. This makes the methods available in your steps.